# Redirecting home to /wp-login.php?action=register

Tags: redirect, translation

As I'm currently using WordPress only as a registration platform for GlotPress I was wondering if it would be possible to somehow redirect users visiting `http://translate.mydomain.tld/account/` to `http://translate.mydomain./account/wp-login.php?action=register`?

`http://translate.mydomain.tld/account/` being my WordPress installation folder (and `http://translate.mydomain.tld/` being my GlotPress installation folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in a plugin or in functions.php

```
if(is_home()){
    wp_redirect(site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register'));
}
```